# Can I make a pie chart based on indexes in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, rows, pie-chart

Could you please help me if you know how to make a pie chart in Python from it?

This is a reproducible example how the df looks like. However, I have way more rows over there.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [["70%"], ["20%"], ["10%"]]
example = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['percentage'])
example.index = ['Lasiogl', 'Centella', 'Osmia']
example
```

Comment: Like I want to see on this piechart that Lasiogl is 70%, Centella is 20% and etc

Comment: use a plotting library to make charts. Have you tried matplotlib? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html

Comment: Please see the matplotlib and try to write your own code attempt. Then update this question with that if you get stuck.

Comment: @Shu check answer if it will work for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib` to plot the pie chart using dataframe and its indexes as labels of the chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = ['percentage':["70%"], ["20%"], ["10%"]]
example = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['percentage'])
my_labels = 'Lasiogl', 'Centella', 'Osmia'
plt.pie(example,labels=my_labels,autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.show()
```